# Binary Tree and Return root node

Tags: recursion, binary-tree

..I'm building a binary tree where the root is given and the children are either root-3, root-2 or root-1 (that is, they hold those number of pennies). So 5 would have nodes of 2,3,4, and so on, until the leaves are 0. Here's my method for making such a tree. I don't understand why the method doesn't return the original node, in this case, the value should be 3.

Any guidance would be awesome.

```
 public GameNode buildTree1(GameNode root){

 int penn = root.getPennies();  
 if (penn < 0)
   {
    return null;
   }

   else {
       root.print();
    root.setLeft(buildTree1(new GameNode(penn-1)));
    root.setMiddle(buildTree1(new GameNode(penn-2)));
    root.setRight(buildTree1(new GameNode(penn-3)));
    return root;
   }
```

Get/Set Methods

```
public void setLeft(GameNode newNode) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
left = newNode;
```

}
   Same for setMiddle and setRight;

Comment: Can you show the set methods?

Comment: i still don't see anything wrong. what is your input and the expected output, and what was the buggy output (just to make things clear)?

Comment: fyi: this is not a binary tree. a binary tree is a tree in which each node has at most 2 child nodes.